# C# project on VMWare and the database is outside of VMWare

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008, vmware

I have a C# project on VMWare and my database is outside of VMWare. It's on my real PC and the VMWare is on the same PC. My question is how can I access my database on my PC ? I have  this class but it does not work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;


namespace EyeCareCenter
{
    class DataBase
    {
        private string connectionstring = @"Data Source =127.0.0.1,1433 ; Network      Library=DBMSSOCN ;Initial Catalog=EyeCareCenter ; Trusted_Connection=True ";
    private SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();

    public void OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {

            connection.ConnectionString = connectionstring ;
            connection.Open();
          //  MessageBox.Show (" Connection successfull ... ");

        }

        catch ( Exception a)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(a.Message + " ");

        }
    }
    public void CloseConnection()
    {
        connection.Close();

    }
    public SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return connection;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: What does "It's not work" mean? What specifically doesn't work. Please don't reply in a comment - update your question.

Comment: Is your VM configured to allow for networking?  If so, are you able to access your host machine from VM?  I.e. this may be VM configuration issue rather than code.

Comment: You need to figure out what your "outside" machine's PC's IP is "inside" your VM. That'll probably be the IP you need to use in your DSN>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a minimum, your connection string is trying to connect to database inside your VM, not on host machine:

> > private string connectionstring = @"Data Source =**127.0.0.1**,1433 ; Network      Library=DBMSSOCN ;Initial Catalog=EyeCareCenter ; Trusted_Connection=True ";

The IP should be changed to that of your host machine to connect to it.  And make sure that your VM is configured for networking, and that networking configuration allows for connecting to your host machine.